# Can someone identify this bug?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I am looking for some help identifying this bug. I am in southern New Mexico, US. There are a handful of these on the inside and outside of all the window panes on one side of my house. They are about 3mm long. They appear this time of year (late April/early May), stay on the windows for a a week or so and then disappear. [image: unknown bug] Hard to get a clear picture as they are so small. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!